# Python list comprehension, invalid syntax

Tags: python

In some part of my program i have this code:

```py
from os import walk

def get_missing_parts(count, directory_name):
  filenames = next(walk(directory_name, (None, None, []))[2]
  parts = [i for i in range(1, count + 1) if not f"seg-{i}-v1-a1.ts" in filenames]
  return parts
```

Traceback

```
  File "/home/td/tmp/g/g.py", line 5
    parts = [i for i in range(1, count + 1) if not f"seg-{i}-v1-a1.ts" in filenames]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You could at least include the traceback and error message?

Comment: Did you miss a `)` on the `filenames = ` line?

Comment: Use a text editor or shell with syntax highlighting, those errors will be obvious ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help in the future, you need to provide a [mre] including the full error message. Just making the MRE should help you find simple typos like this.

Comment: I ran your code and added the traceback. its easier to spot the problem with all of the error details.

Comment: The traceback marks the point where python is sure something went wrong. But the fault is frequently a bit before that. In cases like this, look to the previous line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not close the `next()` function call. Try using an IDE, it will highlight brackets and parenthesis for you to show where you might have forgotten to close one.

```py
filenames = next(walk(directory_name, (None, None, []))[2]
```

Should be

```py
filenames = next(walk(directory_name), (None, None, []))[2]
```

Comment: i found walk function not closed it should be `walk(directory_name)`

Comment: @Gruber Alright, I fixed my answer accordingly. Hope I helped, if my answer is good then please upvote it and mark it as valid :)